# How set start page in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I use node js without frameworks etc. and I have problem, I don't understand how set "start html page" for my first request to server.

I tried do it like this

```
var server = new http.Server();
server.listen(1137, '127.0.0.1');

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('../public/index.html', function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.write(html);
            res.end();
        } 
    });
});
```

When I do request to 127.0.0.1:1137 - I got html in browser, but links to CSS/JS files isn't correct and how I can this to fix I don't know :(

I want get the html page ../public/index.html in browser when I will do first request to my server.

my server location
project/server/server.js

my html-page location
project/public/index.html

Comment: 1) Get/parse `req.path` 2) Do something with it

Comment: If you don't use any framework at all, you have to write the routing code yourself.

Comment: I think you don't really understand what Node.js is.  It's not necessarily a web server, but is often used as one.  If you want this functionality though, you have to code it yourself.  If you aren't doing anything special, check out Express to set up these kinds of requests for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page includes references to images and stylesheets, which you said don't work.

Well, you are responding to every single HTTP request with the contents of the specified HTML page.

When the browser parses the HTML, it will see the image and stylesheet links and issue HTTP requests to those URL's.  But those URL's don't respond with images or stylesheets.  They respond with HTML.

```
GET /index.html
```

yields

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="someimage.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

The browser then requests

```
GET /styles.css
```

yields

```
<html>
...
</html>
```

The browser then requests

```
GET /someimage.png
```

yields

```
<html>
...
</html>
```

You need to make the response conditional based on the request.  To prevent disclosure of information, like @minitech mentioned, you need to be careful not to blindly concatenate the paths.  Then you have to worry about MIME types.

You're really best off using a framework like express.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return different files, depending on the path that was requested.

On the `'request'` handler you are getting a `ClientRequest` object, which has a `path` property. Use this information to return the correct files (`index.html`, the CSS or JS files...). An example request callback could be:

```
function onRequest(req, res) {
  var path = req.path;
  fs.readFile('../public' + path, function(err, contents) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end(err);
      return;
    }

    res.end(contents);
  });
}
```

This is still very basic, you will probably want to handle non-existent files with a 404 result code, return the correct `Content-Type` headers the different file kinds (`text/html`, `text/css`, etc).

**Update**: as minitech recommends, the path should be checked for `../`, which would go up the filesystem and access sensitive files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don’t recommend concatenating those. `GET ../../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.1`